# If element of $G$ has a square root then every element of $H$ has a square root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> If $f:G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$, prove that if every element of $G$ has a square root, then every element of $H$ has a square root.

This is the proof I have so far:

Ley $y\in H$. Since $f$ is onto, $f(x)=y$ for $x\in G$. Every element of $G$ has a square root, thus let $x=z\cdot z=z^2$ for some $z$. Now since $f$ is a homomorphism: $(f(z))^2=f(z)f(z)=f(z\cdot z)=f(z^2)=f(x)=y$. Hence $y$ has the square root $f(z)$. Therefore since $y$ was chosen at random, we can say every element of $H$ has a square root. QED.

I feel like the premise is there but this proof is choppy.

Comment: Are $G$ and $H$ groups? If so, the proof looks mostly fine (just the "*at random*" part is better written as "*arbitrary choice*"). I edited some minor mistake ($z\to y$) in the proof because I assumed it was a typo. Please check the edit history to be sure.

Comment: @M.Winter Does this prove everything I need? I just feel like its missing something.

Comment: Nothing choppy about the proof.  But you english syntax is choppy.  As f is onto, for any $y \in H$ there exists an $x \in G$ so that $f(x) = y$.  And for that $x$ there is a $z \in G$ so that $z^2 = x$.  So as $f$ is a homeomorphism both $f(z) \in H$ and $(f(z))^2 = f(z^2) = f(x) = f(y)$. So for any $y \in H$ there will exist a square root of $y$.  (In particular it can be found as $y^{\frac 12} = f([f^{-1}(y)]^{\frac 12})$.)